# How do I remove the padding without pushing the list-bullets outside of the view?

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the padding-inline-start of a ol (or ul) block. And I have tried the following ways:

```css
div {width:300px;}

#d2 ol {padding:0}

#d3 ol {list-style-position:inside;padding:0}

#d4 ol {padding:1em}

#d5 ol {padding-inline-start:20px}
```

```html
<h2>1. Default CSS</h2>
<div id="d1">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>


<h2>2. Padding 0</h2>
<div id="d2">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>


<h2>3. Padding 0 + List Style Position Inside</h2>
<div id="d3">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>

<h2>4. Padding 1em</h2>
<div id="d4">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>
<h2>5. Padding-inline start 20px</h2>
<div id="d5">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>
```

I would like to know which one is the perfect way.

The fallback of each approaches:

#### 1. Padding 0

It's pushing the whole block outside the view, so it's not good.

#### 2. Padding 0 + List Style Position Inside

It's aligning the left edge perfectly but the text are wrapped around the bullets/digits, it's not good-looking.

#### 3. Padding 1em

It looks very good. But I'm not sure whether `1em` is a perfect solution here because it's just my guess.

#### 4. Padding 20px

It looks similar to the `padding 1em` solution above. But `20px` is also a guess because the default value is 40px (for ul and ol).

Comment: It's not clear how do you want it to look like, even after removing padding-inline-start the list still have possibility of not aligned with the title or subtitle. Maybe if you give an example of how it should look like, then you will get a better answer.

Comment: What kind of reputable source are you looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is "it depends". It depends on what your list use case is. But I'll give one thing to consider. The problem with any fixed padding size or width (as in vals's answer) is that it sets a maximum for the number of list items. If you know the maximum number of items in your list, that's not a problem, just set a padding or width that's large enough. But if you don't know, and would like the space to grow to match the counter size, then the options presented so far don't cut it.

```css
div {width:300px;}

#d2 ol {padding:0}

#d3 ol {list-style-position:inside;padding:0}

#d4 ol {padding:1em}

#d5 ol {padding-inline-start:20px}

#d6 ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: my-counter;
  counter-set: my-counter 99998;
}
#d6 ol li {
  counter-increment: my-counter;
}
#d6 ol li::before {
  content: counter(my-counter) '.';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h2>1. Default CSS</h2>
<div id="d1">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol start="99999">
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>

<h2>2. Padding 0</h2>
<div id="d2">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol start="99999">
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>

<h2>3. Padding 0 + List Style Position Inside</h2>
<div id="d3">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol start="99999">
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>

<h2>4. Padding 1em</h2>
<div id="d4">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol start="99999">
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>
  
<h2>5. Padding-inline start 20px</h2>
<div id="d5">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol start="99999">
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>
  
<h2>6. ::before pseudo + width 20px</h2>
<div id="d6">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>
```

But it can be done, if you mix vals's approach of using a ::before pseudo-element, with putting the li content into another element container such as a div, and using a grid layout.

```css
div {width:300px;}

#d7 ol {
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: my-counter;
  counter-set: my-counter 99999;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}
#d7 ol li {
  display: contents;
}
#d7 ol li::before {
  content: counter(my-counter) '.';
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: end;
  padding-inline-end: 4px;
}
#d7 ol li>* {
  counter-increment: my-counter;
}
```

```html
  
<h2>7. ::before pseudo + grid</h2>
<div id="d7">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li><div>List item<div></li>
  <li><div>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</div></li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>
```

However, maybe putting the li's contents into another container isn't an option. In which case, if the li contains child elements, the grid will get messed up. So, yet another option is to use a table layout. We set the li to `display:table-row`, the ::before pseudo to `display:table-cell`, and set its width to 1px. This behaves like a minimum width, and the final column width will be just wide enough for its contents. Then all the li's contents will be "magically" wrapped in an anonymous table-cell box. Which gives us:

```css
div {width:300px;}

#d8 ol {
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: my-counter;
  counter-set: my-counter 99998;
  display: table;

}
#d8 ol li {
  display: table-row;
  counter-increment: my-counter;
}
#d8 ol li::before {
  content: counter(my-counter) '.';
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: end;
  padding-inline-end: 4px;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<h2>8. ::before pseudo + table</h2>
<div id="d8">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... <em>longer text</em>...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</div></li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer! But variant `#d7` with `display: grid` will work without wrapping in a `<div>`. Of course, if there are no other tags inside of `<li>`.

Comment: @imhvost As far as I can tell, the `div` wrapper is not for layout but only to increment the counter

Comment: Cheers for coming up with a solution for a flexible width that doesn't use JavaScript to determine the widest marker. However, these solutions demonstrate that the rendering of list items would have to be reinvented (and likely have less support and accessibility) to simply adjust the default padding. Goes to show that we could use additional options in the standard specifications for the marker position and width.

Comment: @TimR yes, but you can set `counter-increment` to `li::before`: [codepen](https://codepen.io/imhvost/pen/qBLjZKw)

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best option is not to use the default list style, and just adjust the markers yourself, using counters:

```css
div {width:300px;}

#d2 ol {padding:0}

#d3 ol {list-style-position:inside;padding:0}

#d4 ol {padding:0em}

#d5 ol {padding-inline-start:0px}

ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: my-counter;
}
li {
  counter-increment: my-counter;
}
li::before {
  content: counter(my-counter);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h2>1. Default CSS</h2>
<div id="d1">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>


<h2>2. Padding 0</h2>
<div id="d2">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>


<h2>3. Padding 0 + List Style Position Inside</h2>
<div id="d3">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>

<h2>4. Padding 1em</h2>
<div id="d4">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>
<h2>5. Padding-inline start 20px</h2>
<div id="d5">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your specific needs. Here are some options:

1. **Remove all padding**

```css
#d2 ol {
    padding: 0;
}
```

This removes all padding, but as you noted, can push the list outside of its container.

2. **Keep numbers/bullets inside and align the text with the edge**

```css
#d3 ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This aligns the text nicely but wraps text around the bullets or numbers, which may not be visually appealing.

3. **Specify padding in em units**

```css
#d4 ol {
    padding: 1em;
}
```

This adds some padding, but the amount is relative to the current font size, which can be good for responsive designs.

4. **Specify padding in px units**

```css
#d5 ol {
    padding-inline-start: 20px;
}
```

This also adds some padding, but the amount is fixed, regardless of the font size.

Each of these methods has its uses, and the 'best' one depends on the specific context in your design.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to use `{list-style-position:inside;padding-left :0}` with padding-left 0

```css
div {width:300px;}

#d2 ol {padding:0}

#d3 ol {list-style-position:inside;padding-left:0}

#d4 ol {padding:1em}

#d5 ol {padding-inline-start:20px}
```

```html
<h2>1. Default CSS</h2>
<div id="d1">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>


<h2>2. Padding 0</h2>
<div id="d2">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>


<h2>3. Padding-left 0 + List Style Position Inside</h2>
<div id="d3">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>

<h2>4. Padding 1em</h2>
<div id="d4">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>
<h2>5. Padding-inline start 20px</h2>
<div id="d5">
<p>Normal text</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...Lite item... longer text...</li>
</ol>
<p>Normal text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use padding:1em
`#d4 ol {padding:1em}`

Answer (score -2):

Honestly I think using the padding-inline-start property with a value of 0 on the ol or ul element. This hopefully will remove the padding specifically on the start side of the list items.

if it doesn't really make sense, here's a slight example:

```
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}
```

Hopefully that works out, Good luck on coding bro!

Comment: No, it's the same as `padding:0`. It doesn't work. The bullets are pushed outside.