# Automatically fit list numbers in <OL>

Tags: css

`<ol>` seems to have static width for the number column:

[image]

```js
document.body.querySelectorAll("ol").forEach((ol, n) => 
{
  ol.start = 1000 ** n - 1;
  for(let i = 0; i < 11; i++)
  {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = "item " + i;
    ol.appendChild(li);
  }
});
```

```css
ol:nth-child(4)
{
  /* resize blue list */
  padding-inline-start: 11ch;
}

ol{border:1px solid black;display:inline-block;}
ol:nth-child(1){background-color:lightgreen;}
ol:nth-child(2){background-color:beige;}
ol:nth-child(3){background-color:pink;}
ol:nth-child(4){background-color:lightblue;}
```

```html
<ol>default</ol>
<ol>default</ol>
<ol>default</ol>
<ol>resized</ol>
```

We can manually set `padding-inline-start` if largest number length is known (blue column), but is there a way make it automatic?

The solutions in proposed "[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77004289/how-do-i-remove-the-padding-without-pushing-the-list-bullets-outside-of-the-view)" topic are not acceptable, since they are not automatic and require hard coded values to work.

Comment: You could try the options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77004289/#answer-77062272

Comment: @Alohci the #7 seemed promising at first, unfortunately it uses hardcoded "counter" numbers, so it's not _automatic_

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Alohci [solution with counter-reset | stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77004289/#answer-77062272) should work. Since you mentioned it needs to be automatically, I add additional code to update the start value with javascript. You can change the start number by modify `<ol-element>.style.counterSet`.

## Example

```js
start_collection = ["9", "999", "999999999", "999999"];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.body.querySelectorAll("ol").forEach((ol, n) => {
    let start = 1000 ** n - 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
      const li = document.createElement("li");
      const content = document.createElement("div");
      content.textContent = "item " + i;
      li.appendChild(content);
      ol.appendChild(li);
      ol.style.counterSet = `my-counter ${start}`;
    }
  });
});

function update() {
  document.querySelectorAll("ol").forEach((ol) => {
    ol.style.counterSet = `my-counter ${random_pick(start_collection)}`;
  });
}

function random_pick(array) {
  const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  return array[idx];
}
```

```css
#ol-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ol {
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: my-counter;
  counter-set: my-counter;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

ol li {
  display: contents;
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(my-counter) ".";
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: end;
  padding-inline-end: 4px;
}

ol li>* {
  counter-increment: my-counter;
}

ol:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

ol:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: beige;
}

ol:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: pink;
}

ol:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="ol-container">
  <ol></ol>
  <ol></ol>
  <ol></ol>
  <ol></ol>
</div>
<button onClick="update()">Update</button>
```

Comment: With javascript you might as well simply count number of digits and set proper width.